# How can I print an entire panel control without scroll bars including what is off of the screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, scrollbar, panel

I have my project finally working correcly and I am having a problem with printing it. I want to only print the contents of Splitcontainer.panel1. Whenever I do this it shows me just what is visible on the screen. I would like to get the entire panel and removed the scroll bars if possible.

Here is my code: (Any help is appreciated)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LOTO_Tag_Creator
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PlaceLabels();
        printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintDoc_PrintPage);
    }

    //Ensures labels get placed correctly
    private void PlaceLabels()
    {
        Point lblNamePt = new Point(70, 369);
        Point lblDepartmentPt = new Point(70, 393);

        this.labelDepartment1.Parent = this.pictureBox2;
        this.labelDepartment2.Parent = this.pictureBox3;
        this.labelDepartment3.Parent = this.pictureBox4;
        this.labelDepartment5.Parent = this.pictureBox5;

        this.labelName1.Parent = this.pictureBox2;
        this.labelName2.Parent = this.pictureBox3;
        this.labelName3.Parent = this.pictureBox4;
        this.labelName4.Parent = this.pictureBox5;

        this.labelName1.Location = lblNamePt;
        this.labelName2.Location = lblNamePt;
        this.labelName3.Location = lblNamePt;
        this.labelName4.Location = lblNamePt;

        this.labelDepartment1.Location = lblDepartmentPt;
        this.labelDepartment2.Location = lblDepartmentPt;
        this.labelDepartment3.Location = lblDepartmentPt;
        this.labelDepartment5.Location = lblDepartmentPt;
    }

    private void buttonCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InsertName();
        InsertDepartment();
        InsertPicture();
    }

    private void InsertName()
    {
        if (textBoxName.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            this.labelName1.Text = this.textBoxName.Text;
            this.labelName2.Text = this.textBoxName.Text;
            this.labelName3.Text = this.textBoxName.Text;
            this.labelName4.Text = this.textBoxName.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please add a name", "No Name", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void InsertDepartment()
    {
        if (this.textBoxDepartment.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            this.labelDepartment1.Text = this.textBoxDepartment.Text;
            this.labelDepartment2.Text = this.textBoxDepartment.Text;
            this.labelDepartment3.Text = this.textBoxDepartment.Text;
            this.labelDepartment5.Text = this.textBoxDepartment.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please add a department", "No Department", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void InsertPicture()
    {
        if (this.pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            this.pictureBox6.Image = this.pictureBox1.Image;
            this.pictureBox7.Image = this.pictureBox1.Image;
            this.pictureBox8.Image = this.pictureBox1.Image;
            this.pictureBox9.Image = this.pictureBox1.Image;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please add a picture", "No Picture", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void buttonSelectImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
        OFD.Filter = "Image Files |*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.bmp;";
        OFD.InitialDirectory = Path.GetPathRoot(Application.StartupPath);
        OFD.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (ImageEditor IE = new ImageEditor(OFD.FileName))
            {
                if (IE.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.pictureBox1.Image = IE.useimg;
                    IE.Close();
                }



                // do what ever with result...
            }
            //ImageEditor IE = new ImageEditor(OFD.FileName);
            //IE.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
    PrintPreviewDialog printDialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    Panel panel = null;
    Bitmap MemoryImage;

    public void GetPrintArea(Panel pnl)
    {
        MemoryImage = new Bitmap(pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
        pnl.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height));
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MemoryImage != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, 0, 0);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
    }

    void PrintDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle pageArea = e.PageBounds;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, (pageArea.Width / 2) - (panel.Width / 2), panel.Location.Y);
    }

    public void Print(Panel pnl)
    {
        panel = pnl;
        GetPrintArea(pnl);
        printDialog.Document = printDoc;
        printDialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void buttonPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Print(this.splitContainer1.Panel1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have edited your tags. if you're using winforms please tag your question `[winforms]`. Not everyone is using deprecated technology these days...

Comment: what do you mean depreciated technology? What else should I look at using?

Comment: It's not deprecated, just designated as feature-complete. Anyway, you should use the correct tags, WinForms is more relevant then C#.

Comment: @henkholterman right, if "feature complete" means not actually having any features except forcing developers to all sorts of unneeded code behind hacks, and flickering all the time.

Comment: @badtoy1986 All current .Net and WinRT UI frameworks are XAML-based and share a common mentality and "way to work", called MVVM. Your winforms code will not translate nicely to either a XAML-based framework or a Web app, when it comes the time to upgrade. I strongly suggest you forget winforms forever and use current technologies. Either HTML5 for the Web, WPF for the Windows Desktop or WinRT XAML for "Metro-Style" WinRT applications for Windows 8 and above.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will look into those options. In the mean time, the program is needed at work for created quick picture lockout tags. Does anyone have help for me to get this to work?

Comment: @badtoy1986 - As you noticed the built-in methods just do a screen print. There's a bunch of helpful answers on the right here, your best bet.